# how to make a request to controller in node in my case?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to create a route in my app and access the controller method.

I have something like these in my `route.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var route = express.Router();
var testController = require('../controllers/testController');

//express middleware
route.use(function(req, res, next){
    next();
})

//getting testController.getAll is not a function error 
route.get('/getall', testController.getAll());

//Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined] error 
route.get('/getall', testController.getAll);

module.exports = route;
```

My testController

```
var testController = function(){
    function getAll (req, res) {
        res.send('123456')
    }

    return {
        getAll: getAll
    }
}

module.exports = testController;
```

I am not sure how to make sure `123456` get returned to the request. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

    `route.get('/getall', testController().getAll);`